# Wireless is too slow after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I am working on Dell Inspiron desktop with Ubuntu Linux 18.04. The wireless speed is too slow in my desktop. Following are the details:

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:30:5b:e6:d8:71
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:e005 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Any one can help on this?

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed this after installing ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (Lenovo) - turns out there is some kind of issue with 11n and iwlwifi Intel chips. The solution is to turn it off. 
Check if it works first with:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi

sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Make it permanent with this command:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

I did this and my wifi speeds instantly went back to normal.

Comment: sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
This command gives me the following error message - 
rmmod: ERROR: missing module name.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi

Comment: Here are some instructions for trouble shooting your modprobe module https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/modprobe-command-not-found-929534/